# Center and connect different columns with grid

Tags: r, grid

I want to produce a table which has different columns/column names. How can I connect an centre column 1 so that it is in line with column 2 and column3.

I tried something like this:

```
s<-tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:2], theme=tt1, rows=NULL)
d<-tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:2], theme=tt2, rows=NULL)
a<-gtable_combine(s,jn, along=2)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(a)
```

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provide information about what the object `jn` is and at least an example of its contents?

Comment: I tried different things like this: jn<-tableGrob(a[1,1:2], rows=NULL, cols=c("column 2","column3"), theme=t2). But I have absolutly no clu.

Comment: In your code you have a line `a<-gtable_combine(s,jn, along=2)`, but you haven't defined `jn` in the code, so it's hard to guess what the object is. But then in your comment you define `jn<-tableGrob(a[1,1:2], rows=NULL, cols=c("column 2","column3"), theme=t2)` which is based on `a`. So unfortunately, it's still not possible to know, because you're trying to define each with information you haven't provided.

Comment: You are right. You also can use this as reference. tab<- tableGrob(iris[1:4,1:5], rows=NULL); header<-tableGrob(iris[1,1:2], rows=NULL, cols=c("head1","head2")); jn<-gtable_combine(header[1,], tab, along=2); jn$layout[1:4, c("r","l")]<-list(c(1,2), c(3,5)); jn$layout[3, c("t","b")]<-(c(1,2)); jn$layout[5,"b"]<-1; grid.newpage(); grid.draw(jn) ---- how to eliminate the grid in the first column and the column under it?